# in_array always returns false

Tags: php, arrays

I have this function:

```
function remove_addresse($input) {
    if (!is_array ($input)) {
        $input = array ($input);
    }

    foreach ($this -> message_meta['to_address'] as $key => $address) {
        echo $address;
        print_r($input);
        if (in_array ($address, $input)) {
            unset ($this -> message_meta['to_address'][$key]);
       }
    }
}
```

For some reason in_array is always returning false.

typical $address: `mult3@client.com`

typical $input: `Array ( [0] => mult1.client.com [1] => mult3.client.com )`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why would you expect these to match? ('@' isn't the same character as '.'.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the . is a typo in the typicial input, well then the needle is not in the haystack.

mult3@client.com != mult3.client.com

Comment: Np. Let us know if, is the problem fixed or was it just a typo in the question?

Comment: my test data had the typos in it

Answer (score 0):

`mult3@client.com` isn't equal to `mult3.client.com`, so you should have `false`

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the dot does not match the @-sign. in_array() uses direct match, no regex (and hence no placeholder).